# how to capture the date from this column

Tags: python

```
0       Paperback,– 10 Mar 2016
1        Paperback,– 7 Nov 2012
2       Paperback,– 25 Feb 1982
3        Paperback,– 5 Oct 2017
4       Hardcover,– 10 Oct 2006
                 ...           
6232     Paperback,– 8 Aug 2018
6233    Paperback,– 21 Nov 2016
6234     Paperback,– 8 Jun 2006
6235    Paperback,– 15 Jan 2015
6236    Paperback,– 21 Dec 2016
Name: Edition, Length: 6237, dtype: object
```

tried splitting

```
df_train.Edition.str.split(' ')
```

got the following in Edition column

**<function to_datetime at 0x00000262C3D72DC0>**

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime try to use this method

Comment: you should not split it by space there is `,–` so after splitting it you can convert it by strftime

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean:

```
df_train['Edition'] = pd.to_datetime(df_train['Edition'].str.split(',– ').str[-1])
```

Comment: ParserError: Unknown string format: Paperback,– 10 Mar 2016

Comment: @LancelotDSouza Edited my answer, please accept if it works by clicking the check mark

Comment: When i used the above code got a parse error ,want only the date 10 Mar 2016.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

another way to split using lambda:

```py
df_train['Date']= df_train['Edition'].apply(lambda x : x.split(',-')[-1])
```

Comment: Don't use apply/lambda if there is a vectorized approach!